# Using IF & VLOOKUP to convert value into 3 different values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to figure out a way to analyze a value retrieved from `VLOOKUP()` and sort it into 3 categories.

I want to pull immigration status values and wish to display either Y, N or Unknown. I want to display:

1. Y if: UK National, Irish National, EEA national – settled status, ILtR, Refugee, Other limited leave without NRPF
2. N if: Refused Asylum seeker, No valid leave/undocumented, EEA – no status
3. Unknown if: EEA national – pre-settled status, other, EEA national – status not known, or if the cell is blank.

Also is there a way to get rid of the multiple VLOOKUPs? Maybe something that could look like

`=IF(OR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$J$75,8,FALSE)="UK National"*, "EEA national - settled status", etc*), "Y", "N")`

At the moment I'm using a very long formula of nested VLOOKUPs but this will only allow me to sort into two values. Y for 1. (see below) and N for anything else.

Formula looks like: `=IF(OR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$J$75,8,FALSE)="UK National",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$J$75,8,FALSE)="EEA national - settled status", VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$J$75,8,FALSE)="Refugee",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$J$75,8,FALSE)="Irish National",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$J$75,8,FALSE)="Other Limited Leave without NRPF condition"), "Y", "N")`

Answer (score 2):

`OR` Allows the use of an array of strings:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$J$75,8,FALSE)={"UK National", "EEA national - settled status", etc}), "Y", "N")
```

But it may be better to create a new table of the statuses and there expected output, which would allow better maintenance than hard coding a formula.  Then you can do a nested VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$J$75,8,FALSE),Sheet2!$A:$B,2,0)
```

where Sheet2 contains the second lookup of status and return of `Y`,`N`,`Unknown`.

Or you can fill a column on Sheet 1 with the correct output referencing the new table on Sheet2.

Then you would just reference that column with a single VLOOKUP.